# Problem combining ranef plots of two models with grid.arrange()

Tags: r, plot, random-effects

I have two LMEs:

```
lme1 <- lmer(F1 ~ (phoneme|individual) + (1|word) + frequency, 
         data = nurse_female)
lme2 <- lmer(F2 ~ (phoneme|individual) + (1|word) + 
                   frequency + age + (1|zduration), 
         data = nurse_female)
```

I created simple dotplots `dotplot(ranef(lme1))` of the random effects which creates a plot for each random predictor. I am however only interested in the `phoneme|individual` one which looks like this:[image]

Normally I would use grid.arrange() but I can't get it to only select the phoneme|individual plots. Do you know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A reproducible example would be useful, I hope this example does what you want ...).  I think the key here is to recognize that the `dotplot.ranef.mer` method returns a *list* of plots:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(angle ~ (1|recipe) + (1|recipe:replicate), cake, REML= FALSE)
dd <- dotplot(ranef(fm1))
length(dd) ## 2
```

They're not necessarily in the same order as in the formula:

```
names(dd) ## [1] "recipe:replicate" "recipe"          
print(dd[["recipe"]])
print(dd[["recipe:replicate"]])
```

So you would want something like

```
f <- function(m) dotplot(ranef(m))[["individual"]]
gridExtra::grid.arrange(f(lme1),f(lme2))
```